# Android Glide Button background image

Tags: android, image, button, background, android-glide

There are any was to use Glide with Button's background image?

I tried with code below, but get error for into(building1Button)

"cannot resolve method 'into(android.widget.Button)'

Can somebody help me how to use glide with button background image?

xml code:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/building1Button"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/building1pintest"
            android:onClick="openbuildings1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.109"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

mainactivity:

```
Button building1Button;

....
...
..
....onCreate.....
   
building1Button = findViewById(R.id.building1Button);
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.building1pintest).into(building1Button);
```

Comment: You can use ImageView to load the image through glide and can use onClick attribute on ImageView so that it can act like a button.

Comment: thanks, i gonna try it now